# With Typescript and React, how do I access properties on the React component's default "children" prop?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using React with Typescript.  I have a React component that can take several different React Components as it's children.  Inside the component, I want to check what the type of the children are, and return different code.  Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
type TabProps = {
  ... other definitions ... 
  children: React.ReactChild[]
};

export default function Tab({ 
    ... other props ... 
    children
}: TabProps) {

    const getTabContents = () => {
        const tabPanelComponents: React.ReactChild[] = children.filter((child: React.ReactChild) => {
            if (child.type.name === "TabTitle") {
                ... return code snippet 1 ... 
            } else if (child.type.name === "TabContent") {
                ... return code snippet 2 ... 
            }
        });

        return tabPanelComponents;
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {getTabContents()}
        </div>
    );
}
```

The Tab component might be used like such

```
<Tab>
   <TabTitle> Title 1 </TabTitle>
   <TabContent> Content 1 </TabContent>
   <TabTitle> Title 2 </TabTitle>
   <TabContent> Content 2 </TabContent>
</Tab>
```

Now I know React children have the property ".type.name" by default, but when I try to access it Typescript throws the console error:

Property 'type' does not exist on type 'ReactChild'.

Sorry I am new to typescript, but what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Normally folks use `children: React.ReactNode` as the type for their props. I'm not sure about `React.ReactChild` - try switching to use the ReactNode type and see if that works for you?

Comment: Have you found a real solution @thatDubstepSound?